# iOS7 Safari interfere with jQueryMobile footer

Tags: jquery, mobile, ios7, footer, navbar

I have this code using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2.  It looks like an email app, with fixed header/footer bar and scroll content in between.  Works really well on iOS 6 Safari.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <a ajax-href='@Url.Action("UpdateMsgStatus")/@msgid' data-method="post">
        <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-2x"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    @Html.Partial("_MsgDetailsList.mobile", new List<Message>(Model))
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a data-href="@Url.Action("Reply", "Message")">
        <i class="icon-reply icon-2x"></i>
    </a>

    <a data-href="@Url.Action("Forward", "Message")" >
        <i class="icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I upgrade to iOS 7, the new Safari try to maximize screen by dynamically shrink top address bar and  hide bottom nav bar as you scroll the page.  This puts my footer at the real bottom of the screen.  The problem is when I try to tap the buttons on my footer, it brings back the browser nav bar, squeeze the footer up.  I have to tap the button again to make it work.

Any idea how to solve this?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Seems no way to control browser behavior.  I moved all the buttons to the top of the screen.

Comment: I can't believe Apple made this change...it's ridiculous that they've taken over such a vital piece of real estate like that.

Comment: We are also experiencing the same issue. Tried putting padding below the bottommost button but of course, only a temporary fix just cheating the user to scroll down a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue by setting the min-height property of the ui-page element to 420px with important notification. On debugging I noticed that iOS7 is setting the min-height to 1321px making the tab bar pushed to the bottom.

In my case, I just needed to fix this once on the first screen and after that safari behaved properly

```
#login {
    min-height: 420px !important;
}
```

You can also set this globally to all screens if you want

```
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page { min-height: 420px !important; }
```

Comment: I think this change the default screen height for smaller page so the appears full screen without the bottom browser navbar, right?  I do that on some of my page too.  My original problem was, if you have your own fixed footer toolbar with buttons, you can't tap them without bring up the browser navbar first, making it an unusable two step process.